# Nx typescript error on custom build script

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I would like to create a custom build script that compile multiple files from a single app but I always get compilation errors with nx. Here is a dummy project reproducing the error:

- Create a new monorepo: `npx create-nx-workspace test-error`
- Change nx.json workspaceLayout's property and set appsDir to `apps` instead of `packages`
- Add the npm package to make a new node application: `npm i -D @nrwl/node`
- Create a new application: `npx nx g @nrwl/node:application test-app`
- Create two files ready to be compiles: Copy/paste `main.ts` and name it `main2.ts`
- Add this to tsconfig.json to remove the error that should have popped:

```js
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
```

- Add this dummy script to compile the two files

```js
    "ts-build": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "commands": [
          "tsc apps/test-app/src/main.ts",
          "tsc apps/test-app/src/main2.ts"
        ],
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/test-app"
      }
    },
```

- Compile the app: `npx nx ts-build test-app`

This will throw this error but still output the two files in the same directory (not in the dist folder as planned).

```
npx nx ts-build test-app

> nx run test-app:ts-build

node_modules/@types/jsdom/base.d.ts(5,10): error TS2305: Module '"parse5"' has no exported member 'ElementLocation'.
node_modules/@types/jsdom/base.d.ts(5,10): error TS2305: Module '"parse5"' has no exported member 'ElementLocation'.
Warning: run-commands command "tsc apps/test-app/src/main.ts" exited with non-zero status codeWarning: run-commands command "tsc apps/test-app/src/main2.ts" exited with non-zero status code
```

I don't understand why it show an error message but seems to compile successfully (the main files should have only a `console.log` line of code). And also why it doesn't output the files in the specified dist directory.